# Where are Python's stdlib tests?

Tags: python, testing

Say I wrote a `class` that resembles a `dict`. I want it to pass the same unit test the standard `dict` passes, with maybe some modifications.

Where can I find that code?

Comment: I had to read this three times before I understood it. Between the 2nd and third you made an edit so I don't know if I understood it by reading it three times or whether you edited it so I understood it. Perhaps you could make it clearer, because it's a good question.

Comment: why dont you inherit from dict using `new` and add the custom stuff you need. Then you wont need to worry if you broke `dict` functionality

Comment: @Joe the edit I made was in the title: I included the word 'stdlib' :)

Comment: Hm. Maybe I was tired.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python tests are included with the python source, in `Lib/test`:

http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.4/file/9290822f2280/Lib/test/test_dict.py
http://hg.python.org/releasing/3.3.1/file/8e5812b35480/Lib/test/test_dict.py

Answer (score 1):

To build on Pavel's answer, It looks like python is [using mercurial now](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0385/)

http://hg.python.org/releasing/2.7.3/file/7bb96963d067/Lib/test/test_dict.py

For other tests go to

http://hg.python.org/

click on `releasing/<python version>` > `browse` (on the left menu) > navigate to the appropriate test. The structure at hg.python.org is similar to that of svn.python.org.